# why does typescript ignore the RxJS filter

Tags: angular, filter, event-handling, rxjs

I'm trying to filter angular events but typescript doesn't like it. Using this code:

```
this.router.events
.filter(e => e instanceof RoutesRecognized)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data.state.root.firstChild.data[0])
  });
```

works and outputs any static data I've put into the route config, e.g.:

```
{ path: 'about', component: AboutContainer, data: [{ Foo: 'bar' }] }
```

except typescript throws an error message:

```
error TS2339: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'Event'. 
Property 'state' does not exist on type 'NavigationStart'.
```

So it works fine but the error message is annoying. I could wrap the console.log in a `if data instanceof RoutesRecognized` but seems dirty. Does anyone know how to stop the errors using RxJS ?

Comment: You can change the type to `any`, `.subscribe(data: any => {`

Comment: when I cast it to any it throws an error: `ReferenceError: data is not defined` and `error TS1005: ',' expected.`

Comment: What do your imports look like?

Comment: You must be making a typo somewhere.

Comment: `:e => e` should `:` have to be there i doubt it.

Comment: ah, good pickup @Jai .  the : was a typo, not in my actual code, that didn't fix it unfortunately.

Comment: here are my imports: `import { Component } from '@angular/core';`
`import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ActivatedRouteSnapshot,NavigationStart,RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';`
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';`
`import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: @echonax if I change `.subscribe(data: any => {` back to `.subscribe(data => {` the ReferenceError and TS1005 goes away.

Comment: @JohnPaulVaughan how about `.subscribe((data: any) => {` ?

Comment: thanks @echonax - wrapping it worked a treat. `.subscribe((data: any) => {`

Answer (score 0):

@echonax suggested `.subscribe((data: any) => {` which worked great. I ended up casting to RoutesRecognized to be more specific. This removed the error messages:

```
.subscribe( (data: RoutesRecognized) => {
```